# Related videos on pause not working in JW player 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, media-player, jwplayer

I have JW player 6 and i want to display "Related Videos" on video pause. The function below only display after video finished.

```
related: {
  file: 'http://www.example.com/media/trailer.xml',
  onclick: 'link',
  oncomplete: 'true'
}
```

I've an idea to run the API onPause function to callback but i don't know how to call the related function above.

```
events: {
  onPause: function() {

    // trigger click the "Related Video" button

  }
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Where are you running this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add onpause true.

```
related: {
  file: 'http://www.example.com/media/trailer.xml',
  onclick: 'link',
  oncomplete: 'true',
  onpause: 'true'  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I contacted JW Support to verify the top answer as I could not get the onpause: 'true' to work.  This field is also not available in their documentation.
http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28858/displaying-related-videos/

Here is the response I received from JW Player support when I asked them about this onpause:true capability.

The example you’ve provided is unfortunately false. Currently, we don’t have a way to configure related videos to appear on pause.

Regards, 
Andrew Prelusky 
Customer Support 
JWPLAYER | Your Way to Play

Hope this helps someone else if this is a required feature.